# Hadoop MapReduce Jobs: Get the counter outside of the native jvm

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new in Hadoop and Hbase.

**And my use case is very simple**: I want to get `reduce input groups` count for a job in the run time (i.e get the counter being updated from the initiation to the termination of the job ).

**What I have searched so far**:  All job related logs are written under directory `/var/log/hadoop/userlogs` like shown below:

```
[root@dev1-slave1 userlogs]# pwd
/var/log/hadoop/userlogs
[root@dev1-slave1 userlogs]# ll
total 24
drwx--x--- 2 mapred mapred 4096 Jan 13 19:59 job_201501121917_0008
drwx--x--- 2 mapred mapred 4096 Jan 13 11:31 job_201501121917_0009
drwx--x--- 2 mapred mapred 4096 Jan 13 12:01 job_201501121917_0010
drwx--x--- 2 mapred mapred 4096 Jan 13 12:13 job_201501121917_0011
drwx--x--- 2 mapred mapred 4096 Jan 13 12:23 job_201501121917_0012
drwx--x--- 2 mapred mapred 4096 Jan 13 19:59 job_201501121917_0013
```

Under each `job`, there are directories such as `attempt_201501121917_0013_m_000000_0` (mapper log) and `attempt_201501121917_0013_r_000000_0` (reducer log).

The reducer log directory `attempt_201501121917_0013_r_000000_0` contains `syslog` which contains information about job run. But it doesn't show any information about the counter.

From the jobtracker UI of hadoop, I could see the counter `reduce input groups` being updated until the job is finished but I could not find the same elsewhere.

How can I achieve this? Is there any Java API to get job-wise counters in an another application (NOT in the application which is performing mapreduce tasks) ?

Any other logs or other files which I should look into?

I hope my requirement is clear.

**UPDATE:**

Hadoop version: Hadoop 1.0.3-Intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question in a different way.

Below are the codes:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClusterStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
public class jobclienttest{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                String jobTrackerHost = "192.168.151.14";
                int jobTrackerPort = 54311;
                try{
                        JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(new InetSocketAddress(jobTrackerHost, jobTrackerPort), new Configuration());
                        JobStatus[] activeJobs = jobClient.jobsToComplete();

                        for(JobStatus js: activeJobs){
                                System.out.println(js.getJobID());
                                RunningJob runningjob = jobClient.getJob(js.getJobID());
                                Counters counters = runningjob.getCounters();
                                Counter counter = counters.findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter","REDUCE_INPUT_GROUPS");
                                System.out.println(counter.getValue());
                        }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

The code is self-explanatory. The Class names speak itself.

**COMPILE:**

```
javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:. jobclienttest.java
```

**RUN:**

```
java -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:. jobclienttest
```

And this gives the output of the Counter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know your job id, you can look up your job by id (I think for some limited time depending how soon your cluster cleans up job history).

```
public long getInputGroups(String jobId, Configuration conf) {
    Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
    Job job = cluster.getJob(JobID.forName(jobId));
    Counters counters = job.getCounters();
    Counter counter = counters.findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter","REDUCE_I‌​NPUT_GROUPS");
    return counter.getValue();
}
```

For more reading see Hadoop: The Definitive Guide.

Comment: I am getting below exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecation(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.addDeprecatedKeys(ConfigUtil.java:49)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.loadResources(ConfigUtil.java:40)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:64)
 at jobclienttest.main(jobclienttest.java:21)
`
===>
while executing `Cluster cluster = new Cluster(new Configuration);`

Comment: I have added the version of hadoop I am using. Please suggest the correct jar compatible with this version.

Comment: Most likely you have a mix of jars related to different versions of hadoop. Just google for Configuration addDeprecation NoSuchMethodError. You need to clean up your jar dependencies.

Comment: There is no `Cluster.class` in the jar files I have for the hadoop distribution I am using. I guess, the distribution is very old and there is no `Cluster` API for that version. You answer must be a working one but doesn't work in my environment. Fortunately, I have figured out an another way to get the counter from the older APIs. I'll post a new answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks yurgis :) . Your answer deserves a Vote-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the counters from the command-line without writing any Java:

```
hadoop job -counter job_id group_name counter_name
```

or (for newer versions)

```
mapred job -counter job_id group_name counter_name
```